# 8400GS causes BSOD in Acer M1610 running Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: graphics-card, bsod, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

Title says it all, just installed the Nvidia card, I know this is a driver related issue I just don't know how to fix it I cannot find a driver version that will work not even the one that windows selects for the card, or the one on the disk supplied with the card. Any help will be appreciated.

BSOD output:
[image: BSOD Image]

What happens when I try to install

[image: setup fail]

Any driver that does install causes a BSOD the driver disk says it supports windows 7 and the drivers on the disk cause a BSOD too i'm at a loss of what to do.

EDIT:

Yes I uninstalled the intergrated drivers.
PCIE x16 Card from Gainward
Tried multiple driver versions

Versions that wont install because they cannot pick up card
190.38, 191.07, 196.21, 197.45

Versions that install and cause BSOD
258.96, 260.99, The drivers on the disc (not sure of the version) and drivers from the gainward website (driver version 263.14)

I tried a fresh install on Windows 7 64bit using the 263.14 drivers and that BSOD so I must wonder if installing vista would help at all.

**Re-Opened Thread**

The computer is now running windows Vista 32-bit, I just installed a 650w PSU so I know that the card is now getting more than enough power. Just installed the latest drivers from gainward version 266.77 and still BSOD I'm at a loss for what to do now :(
Tried the latest drivers from nVidia still to no avail, could it be my computer isn't compatible with the card?

**Question**

Why is it older drivers cannot detect the card? eg version 196.6 I downloaded nVidia drivers from Acer for my computer and they wouldn't detect the card.

I really wish someone could help me I can't afford to buy another graphics card.

It's been 3 months surely you guys have an answer

--After Two Hours internet searching--

I came across a few solutions none that worked.

I have

- Replaced the file nvlddmkm.sys with the latest version
- Deleted the services nvsvc and nvlddmkm as advised too someone else
- Deleted my a/v done the other points above and re-installed latest drivers.

Did everything stated in the bullet points, then ran driver sweeper then re-installed drivers, still a BSOD I'm just going to pressume that the graphics card is DOA.

Should there be an extra power connection too support the x16 PCIe slot, im sure x16 slots require extra power and i've got the connection on my PSU just no-where too plug it in

Comment: Wow it's been a while but I'm still here to help. Have you tested the card in other computers?

Comment: I dont have another computer to test it in, i normally use a laptop and the other computer in my house already has a better card in and is under warranty. But windows loads until the drivers are installed which then cause a BSOD

Comment: You really need to test the card it could just be doa. I know you don't have an extra pc at home... maybe a friend could test it in their pc?

Comment: Okay so friends and family members are all using laptops. Not exactly anything I can do there. But im like 99% sure its driver related because the display works untill the official drivers are installed.

Comment: Understood, I would still look at testing the card at some point though because the driver may engage the hardware differently then the builin native driver. However I do have another idea for you I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is there any way i can test the card without another computer?

Comment: I would consider the card DOA at this point... I have installed enough of them without any issues and never have had any driver problems. The fact that the gainward drivers and the drivers on the disk didn't work are a pretty bad sign. Do you have another HDD? See if the drivers install on a fresh OS. If not, you don't have many other options other than testing it on different hardware. Personally I would have considered it toast a long time ago but the fresh OS install is a good test just to rule out any software issues.

Comment: It's been tested on multiple fresh OS installs Vista + 7 32 + 64bit

Thinking of an XP test, frankly i don't care what OS I can get it too run on I only want it too run HDMI for Movies to my TV

Answer (score 2):

We have a ton of these in PC's at my job to provide dual display output. They are from numerous manufacturers: Zotac, EVGA, ASUS, and XFX, We have had good luck with the 196.21 drivers from NVidia, they are a little old but very stable. I'll do a quick search for them online and edit with a link. BTW did you remember to uninstall the integrated drives before installing the NVidia ones? I have run into random BSOD's if the Intel integrated drivers were left in place. Also please let me know what version of the drivers you are using and what version of the card you have (PCI or PCIE and ASUS, EVGA ETC..) I should be able to get this card working for you.

EDIT: [Here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7_winvista_32bit_196.21_whql.html) is a link to the 196.21 drivers.

There may be a conflict with some of the other hardware installed on the PC. Start out by disabling anything in the bios that is not absolutely necessary and try installing the latest drivers. If it still BSOD's try installing the drivers in safe mode after running [driver sweeper](http://www.guru3d.com/category/driversweeper/), let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it does seem to work editing the OP to show what happens

Comment: Must be a standard PCI card? If not the card may be bad.

Comment: IF it is a PCI card download the lastest drivers for the chipset if this is not functioning properly your PC will not be able to detect the card.

Comment: It is a PCIE card x16 in the correct slot. The card works just about, its just when i install the correct drivers to get the correct resolutions it BSODs I even got the latest driver from the graphics card company Gainward, no luck there either.

Comment: @Arch Angel this may be a dumb question. Did you try using 64 bit drivers with the 64 bit install? The ones I linked to are 32 bit. Also does the card work in other computers?

Comment: Yes I used the 64 bit drivers with the 64 bit windows, im using 32bit anyways. I think i found the problem the stock PSU isn't powerful enough, imma pick up a new one soon, see if it helps then if not idk.

Comment: @arch angel did you end up, upgrading the power supply? depending on the processor 300W or more should be fine. I have alot of these running on optiplex 330/gx280's with core2's and 285W supplies and they run just fine.

Comment: Okay if you read what i edited in at the bottom earlier i'll pressume that removed all the nvidia driver files but i'll give that a test later on, already flicked through the BIOS settings and removed my PCI Sound card, this changed the error codes on the BSOD

Comment: @arch angel I added driver sweeper in there because I assumed you would try safe mode after trying it in normal login with everything disabled in bios. If you do them both at the same time ignore driver sweeper, however I am going to leave there for others to reference while troubleshooting similar issues.

Comment: upgraded to a 600W power supply, safe mode boots when normal mode BSODs, I use safe mode to remove the drivers, files and do the things stated at the end of my question then reboot into normal then install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an NVIDIA 8800 GTX (running on a 64-bit Windows 7 system) that I bought a few years ago and it worked fine till 2 days ago.

I noticed a small audio glitch and then some minor video problems (screen flickered only once or twice) - hardly noticeable glitches and may go unnoticed except I'm a retired engineer and notice little things and keep it in mind.

A couple of days later I noticed my computer was in the 'Blue Screen Mode' or BSOD (this computer runs 24/7). After restarting I had 'artifacts' (vertical 'squiggly' segmented lines etc).

The 'minor' audio and video glitches I described above came soon after a Windows 7 update but I didn't take it too seriously until my monitor showed 'artifacts' and the Blue Screen showed up.

I saved an NVIDIA driver from 2010 and installed it over the newer, existing driver. WOW! Amazingly everything was back to normal - this is after spending all day researching the error code nvlddmkm.sys and researching replacement cards.

The driver I used is called:

```
191.07_desktop_win7_winvista_64bit_english_whql.exe
```

S/B found at:
http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/1654/NVIDIA_ForceWare_191.07_Vista__W7_64-bit.html
or
http://wikidrivers.com/wiki/Nvidia_ForceWare_191.07

Comment: I will check that out but i couldnt get the driver 197.** too install

** meaning i don't know the exact version.
But it wouldn't install because it couldn't find my card.